# How do I make my header fixed/sticky on Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, templates, header, fixed, sticky

I am helping out producing a website for a friend but the header isn't fixed at the top, it overlaps the slideshow at the moment. However if I collapse the screen to 'ipad' width the header is fixed at the top.

This is the site at the moment: http://www.testing-30-10-1993.com/

I don't want to risk editing code in case it messes up. I purchased this theme from Template Monster. I just really want the header/nav to be fixed like if you drag the website width to ipad size.

Can anyone help? Alternatively does anyone know anyone/website where I can pay someone to do this? Cheers & appreciate all help. I would add in code but I'm not even sure what section of the code I should copy.

x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not afraid to edit a line of code, go to line 844 of the main-style.css file in the folder to find this declaration:

```
.page-template-page-home-php .header > .container > div {
     position: absolute;
}
```

Change it to this:

```
.page-template-page-home-php .header > .container > div {
    position: relative;
}
```

Otherwise, if you'd prefer not to mess with the theme's files, install a plugin for adding custom CSS and paste in the following code:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    body.page-template-page-home-php .header > .container > div {
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Here's a good plugin for adding CSS: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-pro/

Comment: You are a total lifesaver! I've edited the code and it works (just need to edit size of header but I can do that). Thank you so so so much, you have solved a problem that's been on my mind for weeks. Very appreciated! :)